# how to check rails full app using rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Factories data also define

My Code in controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST create" do
  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "creates a new corporate" do
      post :create, corporate: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:corporate)
      expect(Corporate.count).to eq(1)
    end
    it "redirects to the new corporate" do
      post :create, corporate: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:corporate)
      response.should redirect_to Corporate.last
    end
  end
end

Error
 CorporateController POST create with valid attributes redirects to the new corporate
     Failure/Error: post :create, corporate: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:corporate)
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `corporates` (`id`, `name`, `numberofemployees`, `address`, `phone`, `pending_moderation`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (7, 'sumittest', 5, 'lkjgkklgslkjlk', '99999999999', 1, '2015-05-07 12:56:59.816181', '2015-05-07 12:56:59.816181')
```

Comment: Your question is unreadable.

Comment: @AndyWaite you could have edited the post to add the proper formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you are duplicating ids.

If you are setting the id in the factory, just delete it, the database should take care of it.

Another solution might be to recreate your test database, but it is possible that you get the problem again.

If you debug while running the tests, don't get out with `quit`, or lot of trash will be kept in the database, instead use `continue` and let the transaction to be rollbacked.